ASP.NET Core, proxy through MVC action method
Alongside other endpoints, I have in my Web API (.NET 6.0 or .NET 8.0), I would like to create proxy for some portion of requests I know I just want to pass to 3rd party API, while not really caring about what is being sent/received (so that I don't need to redo all contracts on my side).
Reason why I want to achieve this in a MVC controller is re-usability - authorization and error handling. I want to control who can do this proxy request trough authorization (existing functionality), and if something goes wrong, there's custom error handling (also existing).
Additionally, my _myTypedClient has attached HTTP message handler which adds another authorization header to the request (so caller of my API doesn't need any understanding of 3rd party API auth, and requests to 3rd party API is done on behalf of my application).
I came up with code like this (this is most likely not complete):
// TODO: Add more methods ...
[HttpPost("proxy/svc/{**path}")]
[HttpPut("proxy/svc/{**path}")]
[HttpPatch("proxy/svc/{**path}")]
[HttpDelete("proxy/svc/{**path}")]
public async Task Proxy(string path)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Parse(Request.Method), path);

    // create outbound request content if present
    // TODO: dispose properly
    if (Request.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var memory = new MemoryStream();

        await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(memory, Request.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
        memory.Position = 0;

        var content = new StreamContent(memory);
        content.Headers.ContentType = System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(Request.ContentType!);
        content.Headers.ContentLength = memory.Length;
    }

    // MyTypedClient(HttpClient)
    var response = await _myTypedClient.SendAsync(request, Request.HttpContext.RequestAborted);

    // write response
    Response.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
    Response.Headers.TryAdd(HeaderNames.ContentLength, response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.ToString());
    Response.Headers.TryAdd(
        HeaderNames.ContentType,
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType?.ToString() ?? MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);

    var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(Request.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
    await responseStream.CopyToAsync(Response.Body, Request.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
}


Would it be possible to match any HTTP method?
How could I handle stream better? (I haven't found way how to pass Body directly to StreamContent of my HTTP client)
Should I even do this?! Am I not seeing some massive drawback here?


Fascinating how one can find NuGet after posting question here: Looks like AspNetCore.Proxy is doing what I want to achieve. Still I'm interested in technical solution for my specific case (HTTP) - for educational purposes.

Below are the answer of your all questions:
Would it be possible to match any HTTP method?: There is no build in method to match all the method but you could use HttpMethodAttribute and set below code to accept all HTTP methods:
[HttpGet("proxy/svc/{**path}")]
[HttpPost("proxy/svc/{**path}")]
[HttpPut("proxy/svc/{**path}")]
[HttpPatch("proxy/svc/{**path}")]
[HttpDelete("proxy/svc/{**path}")]
[HttpOptions("proxy/svc/{**path}")]
[HttpHead("proxy/svc/{**path}")]
public async Task Proxy(string path)
{
    // your code
}

How could I handle stream better? (I haven't found way how to pass Body directly to StreamContent of my HTTP client):
Here is the updated code which will help you to answer that question:
In program.cs file register the  typed HTTP client:
 builder.Services.AddHttpClient<MyTypedClient>(client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://thirdpartyapi"); 
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    });

Controller:
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ProxyController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly MyTypedClient _myTypedClient;

        public ProxyController(MyTypedClient myTypedClient)
        {
            _myTypedClient = myTypedClient;
        }

        [HttpGet("svc/{**path}")]
        [HttpPost("svc/{**path}")]
        [HttpPut("svc/{**path}")]
        [HttpPatch("svc/{**path}")]
        [HttpDelete("svc/{**path}")]
        [HttpOptions("svc/{**path}")]
        [HttpHead("svc/{**path}")]
        public async Task Proxy(string path)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(Request.Method), path);

            if (Request.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                request.Content = new StreamContent(Request.Body);
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(Request.ContentType);
            }

            try
            {
                var response = await _myTypedClient.SendAsync(request, HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                Response.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                foreach (var header in response.Headers)
                {
                    Response.Headers[header.Key] = string.Join(",", header.Value);
                }

                await response.Content.CopyToAsync(Response.Body, HttpContext.RequestAborted);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                // Handle the exception, log it, and set the appropriate response
                Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status502BadGateway;
                await Response.WriteAsync("Bad Gateway", HttpContext.RequestAborted);
            }
        }
    }

Should I even do this?! Am I not seeing some massive drawback here?:
There are some drawback of this method: If not carefully managed, proxying requests can introduce security vulnerabilities, especially if you’re not validating inputs or sanitizing headers properly.Depending on the volume of requests and size of the data being proxied, this can introduce performance overhead. Be mindful of the potential load on your server and third-party APIs.
Recommended approach is to use the library like AspNetCore.Proxy that can save time and reduce complexity for the production environment.

Thanks @jalpa-panchal, I realized I can stick with just [Route("proxy/svc/**path")] - though Swagger won't pick this endpoint up. Additionally, the reason why I copied  Stream to memory initially - my fault, there was bug in my code. One question related to your solution, in case of bad request, proxy returns 502. Is this correct behavior?

502 error means server in your situation it is proxy received an invalid response from the third-party API. However, if the problem lies with the request itself let's say if the request is malformed, it would be more appropriate to return a 400 Bad Request status code.so you could adjust your code with the appropriate error handling with different status code e.g. 400, 502,504 etc.

Sure, in my case it's really just proxy - so I'm proxying status code with payload back. Thanks for explanation :)
